# Problems with using link elements nested in td elements and using select dropdown filters data100

Tags: jquery, html, datatable

When I try to use a link in a `<td>`, part of the link is used as the value in the `<option>` for the `<select>` dropdown filter. I would like to have a different link for every `<td>` for each `<tr>`. Below is my code. The dropdown filter for the Office column has the options:

Edinburgh">Edinburgh
London">London

Comment: Unclear what you ask. Provide a minimal working code snippet reproducing the issue

Comment: Please provide your code.